# Chatting long/short entries: Mix string and text?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for a "best practice" to achieve what facebook has done in its chatting system. You can chat "normally" or switch to the messages-page to write a message, which seems to result in the same data-source since there is no really difference (expect in the ui); you see all messages in the chat and on the messages-page.

What I am wondering is how to manage a system in the backend, which is used as a normal chat (-> short messages, I would use string/varchar here) and as a whole messaging system (-> long messages, I would use text here).

Is there any best-practice or idea out there to combine both "message-types" and save resources, e.g. by saving long entries in a different table than short entries, or shouldn't I care about this?

Comment: Why not saving it all as long texts, even if they are "kinda empty"? (less than 10 words)

Comment: Doesn't this cost a huge amount of resources, since they are all saved as BLOB-messages?

Comment: "_which seems to result in the same data-source since there is no really difference (expect in the ui)_" This is simply two distinct _views_ (UI forms) on a single _model_ (data source). This is often reffered to as Model-View-Controller (MVC). The views update when the model changes via the _Observer_ pattern.

Comment: "_e.g. by saving long entries in a different table than short entries_" If I'm understadning correctly, they're all messages. You don't want to go to different places to get **messages**. If you collate different types of messages, how would you ensure they're in the correct order? So I'm pretty certain any attempt to split this data in your model would over-complicate your solution.